# $A \subseteq \mathbb R^n $ s.t. for every continuous function $f : A \to \mathbb R$ , $f(A)$ is closed in $\mathbb R$ , is $A$ closed $\mathbb R^n$?

Tags: metric-spaces, continuity, compactness, normed-spaces

Let $A \subseteq \mathbb R^n  $ such that for every continuous function $f : A \to \mathbb R$ , $f(A)$ is closed in $\mathbb R$ ; then I know that $A$ is bounded ; my question is , is  $A$ closed in $\mathbb R^n$ ? ( If we changed the co-domain from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R^n$ , the answer would be trivially yes , but I don't know what happens when the co-domain  is real line ) . Please help . Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think A is closed in general. There's no easy way I can think of to prove it, but there's some good stuff [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function#Properties_2) under the properties of continuous functions: their images are compact if the pre-image is compact. Images under continuous functions are connected if their pre-image is connected; closedness is not in general preserved under continuous maps, only compactness.

Comment: @Bourque : I know very well closed-ness is not preserved , and I am infact asking the converse question than what you think or linked . I am trying to conclude about domain from given structure of image whereas what you are saying is concluding about image from given structure of domain ..

Comment: Perhaps a search for counterexamples would be warranted. Take for example the closure of the graph of $y=\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ but minus the point $(0,0)$ for $A$. Can it be continuously mapped to a non-closed set in $\mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assume $A$ is not closed. Then there is some $x_0 $ in the closure of $A$, but not in $A$.

This implies that the continuous function $f(x) := |x -  x_0| $ assumes only positive values on $A$, but the closure of the image contains $0$, which contradicts closeness of $f(A)$.

Hence, $A$ is closed.

Comment: How could it skip my mind ... Awesome , thanks :)

Comment: Very nice answer, clear explanation!